# Parcelable.ClassLoaderCreator cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use Jake Wharton's ActionBarSherlock to support actionbars in android projects all the way down to 1.6

I am occurring error like: "Parcelable.ClassLoaderCreator cannot be resolved to a type" and "Type mismatch: cannot convert from ParcelableCompatCreatorHoneycombMR2 to Parcelable.Creator". I am confused where exactly error is occurred.. Can you please guide me, how can I get rid of these errors?

```
package android.support.v4.os;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

   class ParcelableCompatCreatorHoneycombMR2Stub {
   static <T> Parcelable.Creator<T> instantiate(ParcelableCompatCreatorCallbacks<T> callbacks) {
   return new ParcelableCompatCreatorHoneycombMR2<T>(callbacks);
   }
 }
     class ParcelableCompatCreatorHoneycombMR2<T> implements Parcelable.ClassLoaderCreator<T> {
     private final ParcelableCompatCreatorCallbacks<T> mCallbacks;

     public ParcelableCompatCreatorHoneycombMR2(ParcelableCompatCreatorCallbacks<T> callbacks) {
     mCallbacks = callbacks;
   }

     public T createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
         return mCallbacks.createFromParcel(in, null);
   }

     public T createFromParcel(Parcel in, ClassLoader loader) {
        return mCallbacks.createFromParcel(in, loader);
  }

     public T[] newArray(int size) {
        return mCallbacks.newArray(size);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set your target version to 3.2(api 13). I got the same issue and fixed it by setting it. I found a video on [Tutorial: Getting Started with Actionbar Sherlock](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avcp6eD_X2k)